# robots.txt with Zend2 and htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, zend-framework2

I have a domain `domain.com` which is rewritten to `subdomain.domain.com/Home/Index` via .htaccess when no subdomain is given.

This is - of course - not a file in the servers file system but a routing. The page is build with Zend2.

Is it possible that a crawler **does not find** `robots.txt`, located in `public/robots.txt` or ubdomain.domain.com/robots.txt` because of this forwarding?

How exactly does a crawler work to fetch robots.txt?

Comment: If you do not want crawler to find the robots.txt...why you create then one?  The .htaccess (default from tutorial) excludes *.txt or *.css files from redirection and serve them directly!

Comment: I want them to find it but it seems some crawlers indexed the page. That's why I asked if this is possible.

Comment: Crawler will index "normal" pages (your routes from ZF2). Robots.txt is just a instruction for them what they should include/exlude (but a robots.txt is never a page for a crawler)

Comment: So Crawlers find this robots.txt even if there is a rewrite rule?

Comment: If you can access subdomain.domain.com/robots.txt yourself with a browser...then yes

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by creating a router.I reference Matthew Weier O'Phinney for the following solution.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
    'robots.txt'
    array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'robots'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('robots.txt', $route);
```

Then, create a 'robotsAction()' in your IndexController:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    // ...

    public function robotsAction()
    {
        // Set content-type header to text/plain
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

        // perform some logic, add some variables to the view, and
        // you're done
    }
}
```